# C trigger any function as a oneshot function with a timer

Tags: c, embedded

I've built a large program for a wheel-taping machine. I am having a problem with the timing of certain functions.

At some points I have to wait on something like a pneumatic cilinder.

It can occur at some points that a functions gets executed immediately instead of after the set interval. It rarely happens but it can be nasty. It can occur that a wheel rolls out of the machine by accident before it is taped.

On top of that I am also using a 2-byte software timer for every oneshot function and it can be much more efficient.

What I am doing now:
I trigger a function to be called after X ammount of time

```
triggerOneshot(TWO,300);

void triggerOneshot(int C, int I)               // sets the interval for the one-shot timer and selects which function is to be fired.
{
    counter1[C] = counter;
    interval1[C] = I;
    oneshot_bool[C] = 1;
}
```

I continously call:

```
void updateTimers() 
{
    for(j=0;j<8;j++) {
        if(oneshot_bool[j] == 1) {
            if((counter - counter1[j]) >= interval1[j] ) {
                oneshot_bool[j] = 0;
                fireOneshot(j); } } } 
}
```

The timer ISR keeps incrementing 'counter'. When the time is there I do:

```
void fireOneshot(byte s)                                                                    // this function contains all one-shot timed events.
{
    switch(s) { // selector 
        case ONE:       oneshotFunction1(); break;          
        case TWO:   oneshotFunction2(); break;
        case THREE:   oneshotFunction3(); break;
        case FOUR:  oneshotFunction4(); break;      
        case FIVE:  oneshotFunction5(); break;
        case SIX:       oneshotFunction6(); break;          
        case SEVEN:  oneshotFunction7(); break;
        case EIGHT:  oneshotFunction8(); break; }   
}
```

And the bodies of all these oneshots functions contain a unique routine.

```
void oneshotFunction1()
{
    if(airPressureSensor == 1) {
        applicatorUp = 1;
        applicatorDown = 0;
        automatic = 1; 
        message_set = 0;
        setapos(1,15);clreol();// deletes error message
        stop_bool = 1;
        start_bool = 1; }
    else {
        lamp_bool = 1;
        automatic = IDLE; 
        greenLamp = 0;
        start_bool = 0;
        Estop_bool = 0;
        mainRelay = 0; }        
}
```

I can use these oneshots all at the same time, but I never have need for it.

What I want and don't know how to is the following. I want to call triggerOneshot and pass 2 arguements with it, the time and any custom function instead of number. Now I am limited to use the specific functions (void oneshotFunction1()
) I have developed for these oneshot events. But I want to be able to use every function I have and parse it as an arguement for the oneshot event. And I don't know how to realize this.

Comment: Do some research about *function pointers*. And about *structures*. And possibly about *linked lists*.

Comment: And the *continue* statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First with

```
void (*const fireOneshot[]) (void) = {
    oneshotFunction1, 
    oneshotFunction2,
    oneshotFunction3,
    oneshotFunction4,
    oneshotFunction5,
    oneshotFunction6,
    oneshotFunction7,
    oneshotFunction8,
};
```

you can call `fireOneshot[j]()`  (tested so far).

(not tested from here)

With `void (*const fireShot) (int i, char c);` you can 
assign the variable `fireShot` any function `foo` with signature 
`void foo(int, char)` merely by `fireshot = foo` and call it by, say,  `fireShot(7,3)`.

A trigger could be

```
typedef uint16_t WORD;

struct Trigger {
    void (*function)(int arg1, Foo * pointer);
    int fx_arg1;
    Foo * fx_arg2;
    WORD countdown;
} my_trigger;

struct Trigger * ptrigger;
```

Such trigger can then be setup by

```
my_trigger.funtion = my_generic_shot;
my_trigger.fx_arg1 = 08;
my_trigger.fx_arg2 = p_current_foo;
my_trigger.countdown = 300;
```

and when countdown has expired be called with

```
my_trigger.function(my_trigger.fx_arg1, my_trigger.fx_arg2);
```

or by

```
ptrigger->function(ptrigger->fx_arg1, ptrigger->fx_arg2);
```

(except for typos a test would discover).

Comment: @ N. Paul I have a few questions. Why do you use a typedef to substitute WORD by uint16_t? Why not a #define or simply type uint16_t in front of countdown? That just a thing you do?
I do not understand exactly what is what. How is the function which has to be executed called like? Is it my_generic_shot?
And I am also not getting the purpose of fx_arg1 and 2 and (int arg1, Foo * pointer)  and p_current_foo

Comment: I am just used to have unsigned 16 bit values typedefed as `WORD`, because that is a common idiom in my environment (pic32). If you want to have a delayed call to a function *with arguments* you must store them somehow together with the function. The function to be called is `my_generic_shot`. Its address is stored in `my_trigger` by `my_trigger.function = my_generic_shot`. The symol `p_current_foo` is assumed to be a pointer to `Foo` which shall be passed to `my_generic_shot` when the trigger triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer but let me provide another example as below.

```
// oneshot event handler prototype; you can modify as you want
typedef int (*eventhandler_t)(uint32_t counter, void * context);
typedef struct {
  uint32_t timeout;
  eventhandler_t handler;
  void *context;
  bool triggered;
  //... even you can define further
} eventDS_t;

#define MAX_EVENTDS 10
eventDS_t _eventDS_list[MAX_EVENTDS];  // you can implement with linked list as well
unsigned int _eventDS_size = 0;
// You'd better implement this part with binary tree to search faster the handler with interval

int regHandler(uint32_t timeout, eventhandler_t func, void *context) {
  if (_eventDS_size < MAX_EVENTDS && func != NULL) {
    _eventDS_list[_eventDS_size].timeout = counter + timeout;
    _eventDS_list[_eventDS_size].handler = func;
    _eventDS_list[_eventDS_size].context = context;
    _eventDS_list[_eventDS_size].triggered = false;
    _eventDS_size++;
    return 0; // success
  }
  return -1;  // error
}

void updateTimer() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < _eventDS_size; i++) {
    if (!_eventDS_list[i].triggered && 
        _eventDS_list[i].timeout >= counter) {
      _eventDS_list[i].handler(counter, _eventDS_list[i].context);
      _eventDS_list[i].triggered = true;
    }
  }
}

int fireOneshot(uint32_t counter, void * context) {
  //.... something else what you want 
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct myData {
    int a, b;
  } data;
  // somewhere in your main codes, you can call regHandler() to register the hanlder
  regHandler(100, fireOneshot, (void*)&data);
  regHandler(200, fireTwoshot, (void*)&data);
  //.... as you want

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @N. Paul, you're right! the overflow should be considered to finalize this code. BTW, I provided an example to deal with the function handlers which was intended.

Comment: Good answer, some flavour of this is what I do as well. Preferably one wraps this up in the timer driver (usually the RTC driver) and then provide a HAL to the application. As for memory pool vs linked list - if you use linked list, you should let the caller allocate the structs. Although if the list grows too big, the real-time performance will naturally drop.

Comment: @Lundin, I agree with you. I also prefer an array in this case because I had a bad experience with malloc called in ISR which was realized by me so later until issue happens.

Comment: Obviously, malloc is out of the question for microcontroller applications, since it makes no sense there.

Answer (score 0):

`_eventDS_list[_eventDS_size].timeout = counter + timeout;` together with 
`_eventDS_list[i].timeout >= counter` is a *severe error*.

It does not take into accout that `counter` overflows at 2<sup>32</sup> units of time. (Note that 2<sup>32</sup> ms == 7 weeks away from a buggy condition).

Comment: You should either post this as a comment or include it as a side note at the bottom of your other answer, as it doesn't answer the question in itself.

Comment: I wasn't able to comment yet. Seems that now I have achieved enouggh merits to do so

Comment: I am fully aware that the counter could overflow. But it will not happen because none of our machines is turned of long enough. And the ISR is set at an interval of 2 ms so that gives me about 99~100 days